# ¿Qué es lo correcto, "Dejar de verte" o "Dejarte de ver"?

Tags: verbos, pronombres, infinitivo

Un uso posible de la frase sería:

> Es muy difícil que quiera dejarte de ver.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pues lo mismo da, que da lo mismo: ambas son correctas.

De [¿Volver a verte o volverte a ver?](http://udep.edu.pe/castellanoactual/volver-a-verte-o-volverte-a-ver/)

> Cuando tenemos una perífrasis verbal (dos o más verbos que funcionan juntos como si fueran uno solo) junto con un pronombre átono (me, nos, te, lo, la, los, las, les, se) es normal que surja esa duda. En estos casos las dos opciones serían válidas: **el pronombre puede ir pospuesto al infinitivo** (o gerundio) **o delante del verbo auxiliar de la perífrasis** (el que se conjuga). Por ejemplo: Tengo que hacer mi tarea —> Tengo que hacerla o La tengo que hacer; Estoy haciendo mi tarea—> Estoy haciéndola o La estoy haciendo. Así pues, puedes decir Espero volver a verte o Espero volverte a ver.

Puedes leer más sobre este tipo de pronombres, llamados clíticos, en la entrada del DPD de [*pronombres personales átonos*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=elLl31yYnD65MTS9uF), en concreto en esta sección que incide en lo dicho arriba de que *el pronombre personal átono puede ir pospuesto al verbo principal («volver a verte») o junto al auxiliar («volverte a ver»)* ([fuente](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1286280580242509824)):

> 3. **Colocación de los clíticos con respecto al verbo**.
>
> d) Los clíticos se posponen a las formas simples de infinitivo y de gerundio: *Al mirarlo, sonrió; No conseguirás nada regañándome*. Pero si el infinitivo o el gerundio forman parte de una perífrasis verbal, en la mayor parte de los casos los clíticos pueden colocarse también delante del verbo auxiliar de la perífrasis, que es el que aparece en forma personal: *Debo hacerlo / Lo debo hacer; Tienes que llevárselo / Se lo tienes que llevar; Vais a arrepentiros / Os vais a arrepentir; Siempre está quejándose / Siempre se está quejando; Siguió explicándomelo / Me lo siguió explicando.*

Además, en este caso se trata de una perífrasis verbal aspectual ([perífrasis](http://www.materialesdelengua.org/LENGUA/morfologia/perifrasis/perifrasisverbales.htm))

Answer (score 6):

> LAS PERÍFRASIS VERBALES Son construcciones sintácticas de dos o más
> verbos que funcionan como núcleo del predicado. Sirven para expresar
> las características de la acción verbal que no pueden señalarse
> mediante el uso de las formas simples o compuestas. CONSTRUCCIONES
> DUDOSAS
>
> "TENER ENTENDIDO": Construcción lexicalizada (locución verbal) con el
> significado de “creer” PERÍFRASIS CON PARTICIPIO: Pruebas para
> determinar si son perífrasis. La posibilidad de sustitución del
> participio por un adjetivo, por un adverbio o locución adverbial o un
> complemento circunstancial muestran también el carácter no
> perifrástico de la construcción: Lleva puesto el sombrero Lleva así el
> sombrero Lleva en la cabeza el sombrero Tampoco puede hablarse de
> perífrasis cuando el participio puede coordinarse con otro adjetivo:
> Anda enamorado y triste Tengo rotos y sucios los zapatos Son
> perifrásticos los casos en los que no puede suprimirse el participio.
> Lo tengo oído muchas veces. (Es perífrasis) Lo tengo muchas veces *
> Tiene el anillo guardado en la mesa. (No es perífrasis) Tiene el
> anillo en la mesa Llevan marcados veinte puntos. (No es perífrasis)
> Llevan veinte puntos Van marcados cuatro goles. (No es perífrasis) Van
> cuatro goles
>
> © Materiales de lengua y literatura

Por lo tanto no puede decirte "Volverte a ver", lo correcto es "Volver a verte" básicamente porque yo no puedo "volverte" pero sí puedo "verte".

Comment: Por lo tanto no puede decirte "Volverte a ver", lo correcto es "Volver a verte" 
básicamente porque yo no puedo "volverte" pero sí puedo "verte".

Comment: Interesante. Esta respuesta contradice la de @fedorqui aceptada hace 2 años.

Comment: @DGaleano cierto! Y leyendo mi respuesta y el ejemplo que aparece en ella, no es del mismo estilo del que se pregunta

Comment: @DGaleano actualicé mi respuesta con más fuentes, es correcto lo que indiqué yo